# RSA function generates public key (e) always to 17

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I've been working on a project based on RSA key exchange and I have used Crypto++ Library. I followed the guidelines in  https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA and my project works fine. However, I noticed that the public key is always fixed to 17<sub>10</sub> = 11<sub>16</sub> and when I looked in the rsa.cpp in Crypto++ that public key is fixed!

Again, my project works fine, but I just want to know why..

Comment: That's just the exponent. The modulus should be different.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [In RSA encryption, does the value of e need to be random?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5572/13022)

Comment: Thanks I got it by reading the linked article...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed that the public key is always fixed to 17<sub>10</sub> = 11<sub>16</sub> and when I looked in the rsa.cpp in Crypto++ that public key is fixed!
>   ... my project works fine, but I just want to know why..

That's the public exponent, and you can change it. See [InvertibleRSAFunction Class Reference](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_invertible_r_s_a_function.html).

`InvertibleRSAFunction` is an odd name if you are not familiar with the library, but there's a type define for `typedef InvertibleRSAFunction PrivateKey` in [`rsa.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_r_s_a.html). `RSA::PrivateKey`'s `Initialize` function that takes the `RandomNumberGenerator` is the one that creates keys:

```
void Initialize (RandomNumberGenerator &rng, unsigned int modulusBits, const Integer &e=17)
```

The only requirement for the public exponent (`e`) is it must be co-prime or relatively prime to *phi*. *Phi* is Euler's Φ-function, and it's defined as `(p-1)*(q-1)`. It ensures there's an inverse (the private exponent, `d`).

The public exponent is usually selected for a low-hamming weight to make public key operations faster. A low hamming weight means it has very few 1's, and typical values are 3 (0x3), 17 (0x11) and 65537 (0x10001). Fewer 1's makes the exponentiation fast for the public key operations.

For completeness, the public key is ***`{n,e}`***. The private key is ***`{n,e,d}`***. Private keys with CRT parameters are ***`{n,e,d,p,q,dp,dp,u}`***.