# Crypto++ RSA - Encrypt and sign with the same key pair

Tags: encryption, rsa, signing, crypto++

I have a program A which needs to send messages to a program B1. The messages must be crypted, and also signed. Which means only B1 can decode, and he must be sure that the message comes from A.

Also, B1 should not be able to encrypt messages and take the role of A towards another instance B2 of the same program.

Theoretically, it should be possible to use a single RSA key pair, with a key for A and a key for B1. Once decoded by B, if the recovered message is validated (such as by a hash function), it must have been sent by A which did not disclose its key to anybody. In that case, both keys are private (which means they have to be exchanged in a secure channel)

1) Is this recommended or is there a strong argument in favor of having separate encryption and signing steps with independent key pairs?

2) Practically, in the Crypto++ library, the `PrivateKey` class also contains the public key. Is there a way to load a private key only?

Comment: Try here: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Trying at the security stack exchange seems like a good idea. Certainly public keys don't *need* to be literally public for RSA to work. If the private-public key pair is known to both parties, why would it even matter if `PrivateKey` class also contains the public key? No major security flaws jump out to me -- but it all seems somewhat unmotivated. Even if secure, using RSA as a symmetric key cipher wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: @JohnColeman : B should not be allowed to create any of these messages. He should only be able to decrypt and authenticate them. I added this to the question as this clearly adds assymetry.

Comment: In that case I have no idea what you meant by "both keys are private (which means they have to be exchanged in a secure channel)" so the keys are *not* both exchanged on a secure channel after all? In any event -- you really should delete this question here and post it to security stack exchange. With security questions you need something better than off-the-cuff hunches of programmers.

Comment: A third party should not be able to decrypt the messages from A. This means B's key (decrypting key) is private. But a third party should not be able to send messages to B and take the role of A. This means that A's key (signing) is private also.

Comment: When using RSA for crypting, the private key is the recipient's key (decrypting key), the crypting key can be publicly exchanged. When using RSA for signing, the private key is the sender's key (signing key), the veryfing key can be publicly exchanged. If using the algorithm for both operations, then both keys should be undisclosed.

Comment: When I try to close the question, I cannot select security.stackexchange.com, but only dba, meta, superuser, ...

Comment: Just let A have the private key and B the public key. If A takes a message, hashes it (with some clear delimiter between the message and the hash) and then encrypts the combined message and hash with the private key, B (and only B if B is the only one who knows the "public" key) can decrypt and authenticate the message as coming from A. The scheme is clearly as secure as RSA. As far as migrating goes -- you could always delete and repost elsewhere as opposed to closing.

Comment: You might consider learning about [key management and separation](http://www.google.com/search?q=key+management+and+separation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this recommended or is there a strong argument in favor of having separate encryption and signing steps with independent key pairs?

This is kind of a broad topic. There are a number of things you can do depending on your threat model and risk posture. You should probably start by researching [key management and separation](http://www.google.com/search?q=key+management+and+separation).

Since it appears you have selected RSA, then you might want to take a look at [Bleichenbacher 1998 “Million message attack” on RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11149/10496) on Crypto.SE and follow its improvements to 30,000 messages (IIRC). This is where your threat models and risk posture factor into things.

---

> Practically, in the Crypto++ library, the PrivateKey class also contains the public key. Is there a way to load a private key only?

I think you have a misunderstanding of the keys. The public key cannot be disgorged from the private key.

The public key is the `{n,e}` pair, and the private key is either `{n,e,d}` or `{n,e,d,p,q,dp,dp,u}`. If you remove `n` and `e`, then the private key won't work. If you remove `e` alone, then you need to factor `n` to recover `e`. Also see [RSA function generates public key (e) always to 17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36555930/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK, I thought that as the private operations only use n and d, the private key could be just {n, d}, so that you cannot derive the public key from the private key without factoring. But because of the choice of e, it's obviously useless to remove e.